# Node Modules importation issue

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, npm, gulp

### This is my error output

```
PS C:\Users\Us1\MyProject\src\Project.web> npm run create-bundles

> projectweb@1.0.0 create-bundles
> gulp buildDev

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Us1\MyProject\src\Project.web\node_modules\globby\index.js from C:\Users\Us1\MyProject\src\Project.web\gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\Us1\MyProject\src\Project.web\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Us1\MyProject\src\Project.web\gulpfile.js:5:14) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

The command `create-bundles` executes `gulp buildDev` for bulding node_modules for the dev. env.

### This is my dump

`PS > npm -v`

9.6.2

`PS > node -v`

v18.15.0

`PS > gulp -v`

CLI version: 2.3.0

Local version: 3.9.1

`PS > yarn -v`

1.22.19

My host environment is a x64-bit windows 11 enterprise edition virtual machine with visual studio enterprise 2022.

### I have tested the following wihtout success

#### 1) Knowledge base research

I've searched stackoverflow database and found [@Requel0's solution](https://github.com/potree/potree/issues/655#issuecomment-496802752) but they didn't give the versions neither for Node nor Gulp.

In the same thread, [@Nogit's prposal](https://github.com/potree/potree/issues/655#issuecomment-507008347) recommends to switch back to node 10.16.0 confirming that "*Node 12 and Gulp 3 aren't compatible*". What prompted to try a search  version compatibility matrix.

#### 2) Tried to find version compatibility matrix between gulp and node,

No reasult neither from Gulp maintainers nor from Node's

#### 3) Switched to Yarn and tried and upgraded gulp

```
PS > yarn add gulp
....

success Saved 102 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ gulp@4.0.2
info All dependencies
├─ append-buffer@1.0.2
├─ arr-filter@1.1.2
├─ array-initial@1.1.0
├─ array-last@1.3.0
├─ array-sort@1.0.0
├─ async-each@1.0.6
├─ async-settle@1.0.0
├─ bach@1.2.0
├─ binary-extensions@1.13.1
├─ buffer-equal@1.0.1
├─ call-bind@1.0.2
├─ chokidar@2.1.8
├─ cliui@3.2.0
├─ code-point-at@1.1.0
├─ collection-map@1.0.0
├─ concat-stream@1.6.2
├─ copy-props@2.0.5
├─ d@1.0.1
├─ default-compare@1.0.0
├─ default-resolution@2.0.0
├─ define-properties@1.2.0
├─ duplexify@3.7.1
├─ each-props@1.3.2
├─ end-of-stream@1.4.4
├─ es5-ext@0.10.62
├─ es6-iterator@2.0.3
├─ ext@1.7.0
├─ fast-levenshtein@1.1.4
├─ find-up@1.1.2
├─ flush-write-stream@1.1.1
├─ fs-mkdirp-stream@1.0.0
├─ get-caller-file@1.0.3
├─ get-intrinsic@1.2.0
├─ glob-stream@6.1.0
├─ glob-watcher@5.0.5
├─ gulp-cli@2.3.0
├─ gulp@4.0.2
├─ has-property-descriptors@1.0.0
├─ hosted-git-info@2.8.9
├─ interpret@1.4.0
├─ invert-kv@1.0.0
├─ is-binary-path@1.0.1
├─ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
├─ is-utf8@0.2.1
├─ is-valid-glob@1.0.0
├─ json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@1.0.1
├─ just-debounce@1.1.0
├─ last-run@1.1.1
├─ lazystream@1.0.1
├─ lcid@1.0.0
├─ lead@1.0.0
├─ liftoff@3.1.0
├─ load-json-file@1.1.0
├─ matchdep@2.0.0
├─ micromatch@3.1.10
├─ mute-stdout@1.0.1
├─ next-tick@1.1.0
├─ normalize-package-data@2.5.0
├─ number-is-nan@1.0.1
├─ object.assign@4.1.4
├─ object.reduce@1.0.1
├─ ordered-read-streams@1.0.1
├─ os-locale@1.4.0
├─ path-dirname@1.0.2
├─ path-exists@2.1.0
├─ pinkie@2.0.4
├─ pump@2.0.1
├─ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
├─ read-pkg@1.1.0
├─ readdirp@2.2.1
├─ remove-bom-stream@1.2.0
├─ replace-homedir@1.0.0
├─ require-directory@2.1.1
├─ require-main-filename@1.0.1
├─ resolve-options@1.1.0
├─ semver-greatest-satisfied-range@1.1.0
├─ set-blocking@2.0.0
├─ spdx-correct@3.2.0
├─ spdx-exceptions@2.3.0
├─ stack-trace@0.0.10
├─ stream-exhaust@1.0.2
├─ stream-shift@1.0.1
├─ strip-bom@2.0.0
├─ sver-compat@1.5.0
├─ through2-filter@3.0.0
├─ to-absolute-glob@2.0.2
├─ to-through@2.0.0
├─ type@1.2.0
├─ typedarray@0.0.6
├─ undertaker-registry@1.0.1
├─ undertaker@1.3.0
├─ unique-stream@2.3.1
├─ upath@1.2.0
├─ v8flags@3.2.0
├─ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4
├─ vinyl-fs@3.0.3
├─ vinyl-sourcemap@1.1.0
├─ which-module@1.0.0
├─ wrap-ansi@2.1.0
├─ y18n@3.2.2
├─ yargs-parser@5.0.1
└─ yargs@7.1.2
Done in 71.53s.

PS > yarn -v

CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

Tested the `yarn creadte-bundles` command with sames issues

#### 4) Shrinkwrapped the package

by creating the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file under the project directory as recommended by another front-ender.

```
{
      "dependencies": {
        "graceful-fs": {
            "version": "4.2.2"
         }
      }
}
```

Without success.

#### 5) Retested the process from scratch

```
PS > npm clear cache --force
PS > npm clear verify

PS > npm create-bundles
```

My research helped me not. Hélas !

Comment: did you try to migrate gulp to gulp-4 , and migrate gulp file to the new es6 module ?

Comment: Good morning @MohamedTalaat, and thank you for prompt reaction.

I've upgraded gulp to 4.0.2 as stated above. 

I look foreward with ES6

Comment: can you share your gulp-file ?